# Remove :8080 from url with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When i type my url (without trailing slash!)

http://example.com/something

it redirects to

http://example.com:8080/something

while

http://example.com/something/

works fine.

Given that I cannot touch apache configuration it is possible to redirect

http://example.com:8080/something to http://example.com/something/

using only .htaccess in my site 'something' directory?

I've tried several rewrite rules, but none seems to work... In particular, I cannot get how to write the pattern matching the :8080 part.

Tried

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 8080
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/something/$1 [P,L]
```

but got Page not found error...

Btw, there's a specific common reason for apache to redirect to :8080 if there's no trailing slash?

Comment: Are you actually running something on 8080?  This sounds like it could be a case of your browser aggressively caching some earlier 301 redirect. Does it behave the same way if you try it in a new private/incognito browser window?

Comment: Yes. Tried with three different browsing, clearing cache, incognito windows... Yet, it's a problem that must be solved in any case, for my website cannot work well with :8080 for several reasons